# React: Calling component method via ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Component like below. This component is being used with a `ref` elsewhere. Is there a way for me to call `myMethod` via the `ref`?

```
class MyView extends Component {
  myMethod() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({
    reduxState: state
  })
)(MyView)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Create the container component using connect like this

```
export default connect((state) => ({
    reduxState: state
  }), null, null, { withRef: true }
)
```

Please take a look at `connect` documentation here

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

In short(from the documentation) : [withRef] (Boolean): If true, stores a ref to the wrapped component instance and makes it available via getWrappedInstance() method.

Now in order to use `myMethod` using component ref

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.refs.component.getWrappedInstance().myMethod();
}

render() {
  return (
    <MyView ref="component" />
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but the recommended way to set refs is by avoiding string literals like so `ref={c => this.myComponent = c}`. Also appears that `wrappedInstance` is available on the `ref` object.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't follow - what do you mean by ref object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this._myViewInstance.myMethod();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div><MyView ref={ref => this._myViewInstance = ref}/></div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the example above due to `connect`